# Mvvmcross share plugin not working for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.winphone

I have the 4.3 version of the SHare Plugin for windows phone 8.1 and my core project installed.

```
public class SharePluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Share.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
```

When i try to add in the viewmodel constructor it throws unable to load plugin exception, same when i Try to

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxShareTask>();
```

Couldnt find much digging into the exception?

i even tried the following in app.cs of core

```
 MvvmCross.Plugins.Share.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```

Comment: Did you make sure the platform specific implementation is referenced in your Windows Phone 8.1 project?

Comment: Apologies for the Very delayed response .. i had to take time away from the personal project in order to emigrate to a new country. And just restarted working on it now .. , yes i have the plugin installed in my uwp, core and xamarin forms project ,and yet it is still not able to resolve the task ?

Comment: I feel there is something fundamental that I am missing , i have stepped through the code and it hits the Load in the bootstrapper , but when i try resolve .. i get an exception